# Xammp Virtualhost Always Redirecting To htdocs

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost, htdocs

Been stuck on this one for a little while now. Always get redirected to the index of htdocs.

I've ensured NameVirtualHost is un-commented.

Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf is un-commented.

I've tried changing the directives under the directory from;

```
Order allow, deny
Allow from all
```

To

```
Require all granted
```

I've restarted Apache multiple times, flushed DNS.

My files currently look like below;

### httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/development"
   ServerName testsite.dev
   ServerAlias www.testsite.dev
   <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/development">
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

### hosts

```
127.0.0.1             localhost
127.0.0.1             www.testsite.dev
```

Am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is an .htaccess with just basic mod rewrite. If I run a getcwd die on the index.php it returns C:/xammp/htdocs. My virtualhost now refuses to connect instead of redirecting.